# DNS queries get routed to localhost on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, domain-name-system

For some reason, all DNS queries on one of my Ubuntu 9.04 boxes get routed to localhost, which results in no domain names being resolved. When trying for instance `dig example.com`, it hangs for ~20 seconds, before quitting with the message "`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`". However, `dig example.com @193.75.75.75` returns the correct result immediately. This problem applies to all DNS queries, not only from `dig`.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
193.75.75.75
193.75.75.193
```

I do not have a .digrc, NetworkManager has been uninstalled, and the network is otherwise working (e.g. I can use it normally for hosts in /etc/resolv.conf). I do not have a local DNS server installed, and `nmap` confirms that nothing is listening on port 53. I have several other boxen running Ubuntu 9.04 on the same network, DNS is working fine on all of them.

I have used strace to confirm that dig actually reads `resolv.conf`:

```
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 6
(...)
read(6, "193.75.75.75\n193.75.75.193\n"..., 4096) = 27
```

I have also used tcpdump to confirm that the problem is indeed DNS queries getting routed to localhost:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i lo
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
14:11:54.175580 IP localhost.45910 > localhost.domain: 38233+ A? example.com. (29)
14:11:54.175633 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP localhost udp port domain unreachable, length 65
14:11:55.175542 IP6 ip6-localhost.54963 > ip6-localhost.domain: 38233+[|domain]
14:11:55.175575 IP6 ip6-localhost > ip6-localhost: ICMP6, destination unreachable[|icmp6]
```

I am out of ideas for resolving this issue, so any input and suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A record in /etc/resolv.conf should look like

```
nameserver 193.75.75.75
```

Comment: I cannot belive i didn't see that, and went off on a wild hunt with strace, nc, tcpdump, and friends... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

The format of `/etc/resolv.conf` is incorrect, it should read:

```
search domain.com
nameserver 193.75.75.75
nameserver 193.75.75.193
```

The search line is of course optional. If it exists it will be used to qualify hostnames, eg. looking up the address for `router` will return the address for `router.domain.com`

Answer (score -2):

If you've changed this recently, have you tried "service network restart" or restarting all of the server?

Sounds pretty newb, but that's what it takes when resolv.conf is modified.

Comment: You don't have to restart any networking after modifying /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't even have a *service* command. If anything restarting networking will most likely overwrite resolv.conf